# React: how do I add multiple styling classes within a ternary?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using `makeStyles` within my component, but want to add a ternary to switch between 2 different styles.

I have the following:

Import ing classNames

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
```

And using it within my component:

```
            <Badge
              className={
                badgeProps.badgeContent === ''
                  ? classNames(classes.MuiBadge, classes.MuiBadgeDotted)
                  : classNames(classes.MuiBadge, classes.MuiBadgeNumber)
              }
```

But none of these work. Inspecting the element I don't see any classes appearing.

Would anyone know how I could achieve this?

Comment: What is the `classNames` function, and what's the `classes` object?

Comment: It's imported from `import classNames from 'classnames';`

Comment: Hmm, it's possibly a timing issue. For the sake of ruling it out, if you set two constants before the render for each of those classname sets, then perform the ternary - does it work?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you make a live Stack Snippet illustrating the problem?

Comment: `classnames.module.css` ? react loos for .module.css to read styles

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% sure but first try with 
`import classnames from "classnames"`

And second you can do

```
classnames(classes.MuiBadge, {
    [classes.MuiBadgeDotted]: badgeProps && !badgeProps.badgeContent,
    [classes.MuiBadgeNumber]:  badgeProps && badgeProps.badgeContent
})
```

Refer for more info
https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames#usage

Comment: Have courtesy to provide the reason of marking an answer as not useful. People are here to help, using their precious piece of time.